# How do I calculate the confidence interval of an ICC?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, intraclass-correlation

Here's the output from my the summary of lmer function which I used to calculate the ICC.

```
   Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
   Formula: CareChange ~ 1 + (1 | PROVIDER)
      Data: MEA_data_1

   REML criterion at convergence: 35.2

   Scaled residuals: 
       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
   -0.3093 -0.2829 -0.2711 -0.2599  3.6206 

   Random effects:
    Groups            Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
    PROVIDER          (Intercept) 0.0003096 0.01759 
    Residual                      0.0660667 0.25703 
   Number of obs: 239, groups:  PROVIDER_CALENDAR, 14

   Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error t value
        (Intercept)  0.07119    0.01742   4.086

   ICC = 0.0003096 /(0.0003096 +0.0660667 ) = 0.004664315
```

I did not find any literature that shows how to calculate the CI for this    ICC value. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

A straightforward way to calculate a confidence interval would be to create a bootstrapped distribution, then obtain the relevant quantiles from that distribution.  This can be done as a parametric or nonparametric bootstrap, depending on what assumptions you're comfortable with.  Generally, if you accept a Normal distribution for the random effects, a parametric bootstrap is also appropriate.

Since you're using R, the `lme4` package offers a very nice parametric bootstrap function, `bootMer()` to calculate a bootstrapped distribution of any statistic of interest derived from a random effects model.  The parametric method is fully implemented, which simulates the model of interest using new values of the random effects with each iteration.  New values are drawn from a Normal distribution using parameters derived from the mixed model.  See the documentation in `bootMer()` for some detail on control over what effects get bootstrapped.  Set your own number of iterations, but 1000+ is a good rule of thumb.

To calculate this in R, you need to fit the random effects model and pass a function to `bootMer()` that calculates the statistic of interest.  An example implementation is below:

*Example Code using R*

```
#Make some mocked data
library(lme4)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(2024)  #For the Bell Riots
id <- factor(seq(1, 15))
id.mu <- rnorm(15, 10, 5)
mydat <- NULL
for (a in 1:length(id)){
  score <- rnorm(2, id.mu[a], 3)
  id.fr <- data.frame(id=id[a], score1=score[1], score2=score[2])
  mydat <- rbind(mydat, id.fr)
}
mydat <- melt(mydat, id.vars='id', value.name='score')

#Create function to calculate ICC from fitted model
calc.icc <- function(y) {
  sumy <- summary(y)
  (sumy$varcor$id[1]) / (sumy$varcor$id[1] + sumy$sigma^2)
}

#Fit the random effects model and calculate the ICC
mymod <- lmer(score ~ 1 + (1|id), data=mydat)
summary(mymod)
calc.icc(mymod)

#Calculate the bootstrap distribution
boot.icc <- bootMer(mymod, calc.icc, nsim=1000)

#Draw from the bootstrap distribution the usual 95% upper and lower confidence limits
quantile(boot.icc$t, c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need, here's another solution that I ended up with using the irr package to bootstrap this more easily.
(And less clever too, but if it can help future users ...)

I know the package gives you a confidence interval as well as the ICC package but if you're bothered because of the distribution and need a bootstrap:

```
#create the matrix needed for your task
matrix <- select(dataframe, var1, var2) 

#you need to define the model, type and unit according to the question you're asking, here's for the example
irr:icc(matrix, model ="twoway", type = "agreement", unit = "single") 

#New fuction, [7] is to get the value we want (icc in this case)
icc.boot <- function(data,x) {irr::icc(data[x,], model ="twoway", type = "agreement", unit = "single")[[7]]} 

#bootstsrap distribution with 10 000 samples in this example
boot <- boot(matrix,icc.boot, 10000) 

# get the confidence interval 
quantile(boot$t,c(0.025,0.975)) 

# If you're unsure of the number of samples to choose, you can get a look of the distribution of the bootstrap 
hist(boot)
```

I hope it helps.